# Arch Linux KDE not saving monitor settings

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, multiple-monitors

I am trying to get 2 monitors setup.

I have Radeon HD 4800, using the open-source driver. 64bit.
When i change the monitor settings in KDE it changes, but when i reboot: the monitors is going back to duplicated (screen settings have not been saved).

This is the settings i want:
[image]

How can i make the system automaticly use these settings at boot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it. Made a script 1920x2.sh in /etc/X11.

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --auto --output DVI-1 --auto --right-of DVI-0
```

Added this script to Alt + F2: Autostart.
Maybe not the best solution, but i works.

Answer (score 2):

To try to troubleshoot this, launch KDE from the Linux console and check its error output. Also check the Xorg log (usually found on `/var/log/xorg.0.log`). You may need to generate a config file manually. You could also try running `display settings` as root.

Comment: What is the command for running it in the console? "bash: display: command not found"

Comment: Check in process list name this program. Probably this program have name `kde`+ Sth. I think you may easy found this using `TAB` auto- completion syntax.